# How to add remove zoomControl on google map base on size

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps

I saw an [the website of google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#Adding_Controls_to_the_Map) that we could add/remove the `zoomControl` base on the map size.
But the page doesn't explain how to do this.

My objective would be to remove the zoom control on smartphone, so under `576px` I would like the zoom control to be hidden.

I'm working with angular but do not wish to subscribe to the screen size, but would like to let google do that on his self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Google map doesn't accept such variable**, but it's mentioned that the control will be hidden at 200px width, and to disable this you should explicitly mention it.

So if you wish to do that, you'll have to go with a little bit of javascript.

First check the screen width of device then set zoomControl property based on that. For example:-

```js
function initMap(): void {
  let zoomControl = true;
  if(window.innerWidth < 576) zoomControl = false;
  const map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map") as HTMLElement,
    {
      zoom: 4,
      center: { lat: -33, lng: 151 },
      zoomControl: zoomControl,
      scaleControl: true,
    }
  );
}

declare global {
  interface Window {
    initMap: () => void;
  }
}
window.initMap = initMap;
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my initial question, I **do not** wish to subscribe to the screen size but would rater use  the default logic from google, since I saw they have one.

Comment: They have not mentioned anywhere that we can customize that behavior. They have only written that "By default, all the controls disappear if the map is smaller than 200x200px. You can override this behavior by explicitly setting the control to be visible." In my understanding this means that we can only show controls on mapsize less than 200px*200px by explicitly setting them true.

Comment: Okey thx, I miss readed it then.